# 6502 Assembler - The RTS command and the stack

Tags: assembly, subroutine, 6502

I have to answer the following question about the 6502 assembly language:

"On the stack, there are the following values (top element first): `0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06`
At address `0xc000` is the instruction `jsr 0xABCD`. Which value will be stored in the program counter after the fetch/execute cycle and what will be the top element of the stack?"

I know that the program counter will be `0xABCD`, but I'm confused about the stack elements. I know that in the 6502 architecture, the stack grows from the top to the bottom (from `0x01FF` to `0x0100`). So, I assume, the stack pointer is pointing to the element `0x01`, right?

Now, the return address should be `program counter + 3`, because there is the `next` command, so I would say, `0xc003` will be pushed on the stack, but in little endian order, so `c0` will be the top element. Is that correct?

Comment: I would call the starting point of the stack (0x1ff) the bottom and 0x100 the top. In LE machine the _consistent_ model would be to store '03' in a lesser address.

Comment: Just a warning: In 6502, JSR pushes (return address - 1) to the stack. That is, RTS increments it after pulling.

Comment: @cyco130 is there any rationale behind such a design? I find it quite weird to store the address-1 instead of the actual address of the next instruction the execution will continue from.

Comment: @BarbaraKwarc I don't have a definitive answer, I can only speculate: I know the 6502 always fetches two bytes on the first two cycles of each instruction. For 1-byte opcodes, it throws the extra one away and doesn't further increment PC (which was already incremented to fetch the thrown away second byte). For 2-byte opcodes, it uses both bytes and does increment PC. And for 3-byte ones, it increments PC, fetches the final byte, uses it, and increments the PC once more. In JSR (a 3-byte opcode), it must be pushing the program counter to the stack before incrementing PC for the last time.

Comment: Yeah, my guess was that incrementing the PC is the last stage of every machine cycle, hard coded, so it has to do it anyway (after popping it from the stack), and to compensate for that, it pushes the address 1 less (which isn't that hard, if it pushes it before incrementing the PC in the last stage). But it would be nice to have it backed up by some official documentation. And the fact that the conditional jumps use the address of the next instruction for calculating the offsets, kinda puts me off track with this speculation :q

Answer (score 7):

Start with the `S` register equal to `$F9`, meaning everything after that in the `$0100` page is the stack.  Memory contents are as follows:

```
$01FA: 01 02 03 04 05 06

$ABCD: A6 23       LDX $23
; rest of the body of the subroutine
$AC03: 60          RTS

$C000: 20 CD AB    JSR $ABCD
$C003: BD 40 06    LDA $0640,X
```

The `JSR` instruction pushes the address of the *last byte* of the instruction.  In this case, the address of the last byte is `$C002`.  The high byte is pushed first so that the low byte is in the lower address:  push `$C0`, then push `$02`, then jump to `$ABCD`.  After this, the stack looks like this, with `$C002` in little-endian byte order at the top, and `S` has become `$F7`.

```
$01F8: 02 C0 01 02 03 04 05 06
```

The subroutine at `$ABCD` will end with the `RTS` instruction, here shown at `$AC03`. This instruction pulls the low and high bytes of the program counter. And then because the return address points at the last byte of the previous instruction, it *adds 1*. `$C002` plus one is `$C003`, the address of the first byte of the next instruction in the caller.

Comment: related: https://www.masswerk.at/6502/6502_instruction_set.html is a pretty detailed instruction-set reference.  It confirms that `rts` pops into PC and then increments PC by 1, which balances out the offset that JSR builds in to the return address.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what happens on a jsr is

```
stack[stack_pointer] = return_high
stack_pointer--
stack[stack_pointer] = return_low
stack_pointer--
pc = jsr address
```

so if you are claiming that your stack pointer is pointing at the 0x01 and 0x02 is a lower/smaller address then 0x01 and 0x02 will be overwritten and when you hit your subroutine the stack will be pointing at 0x03.

Comment: answer would be clearer with a table... address -> value

Answer (score -2):

I'm pretty sure that this is how it works:

First it takes the distance to the subroutine. If it's backwards, it puts it through a not gate. It then decrements and pushes that number to the stack, and moves up or down that far. When you want to return, it pulls from the stack, increments and moves back to the starting point and then continues the program.

For example:

```
jsr do_stuff
brk

do_stuff:
  lda #$00
  rts
```

First we jump forward `02`, and push `01` (`02` - 1) to the stack. We then `lda #$00`. When we `rts` we pull `01` from the stack, add 1 to it (`02`), then jump back that far. And now we exit.

Comment: According to https://www.masswerk.at/6502/6502_instruction_set.html , `jsr`'s operand is the *absolute* address, not relative distance.  So the assembler + linker just have to figure out the absolute address of `do_stuff` and put that in the machine code.  (Even on CPUs like 8086 where call / jmp use relative distance, it wouldn't be a NOT *gate* in the CPU, it would be binary subtraction in the assembler to generate the machine code.  At run-time, the CPU would do binary addition to calculate the new PC.)

Comment: Also, `jsr` pushes a *return* address, the address after the JSR instruction.  Not an address that depends on the target (subroutine address).

Comment: Oh, you were thinking that the return address would be relative.  It's actually absolute.  If it only knew how far away from `do_stuff` to return to, that wouldn't help because it doesn't know what address the last JSR was to, and `rts` doesn't take an operand to let the CPU know that.  `rts` actually just pops 2 bytes from the stack into the program counter and increments PC by 1 (because JSR pushes return_address - 1).